# ¿Cómo puedo modificar Cards en Bootstrap 5 para que no se vea el contorno del card?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Estoy tratando de mejorar mi conocimiento con bootstrap y customizar CSS.

Bootstrap tiene diferentes estilos de Cards.

A continuacion dejo el más similar a lo que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo que yo necesito en vez de texto un botón, eso imagino que lo puedo hacer simplemente reemplazando el texto por un botón.

Sería algo similar a:

```
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Descripción del producto</p>
              <button type="submit" style="background: #f0db41; border-radius: 10px; width: 250px; border: 0; color: #194644;"><b>Conocer más</b></button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Y actualmente se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la parte interesante es que necesito que sea un recuadro transparente algo mas o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer un grid similar a esto, las lineas punteadas no tendrian fondo las agregue porque fue la primera imagen que encontre en google pero la idea es hacer un grid con puntos o lineas punteadas y que los productos no tengan ningun recuadro, seria literalmente la imagen en .png para tener transparencia al fondo de la pagina, y abajo el nombre, alguna caracteristica como el ejemplo en gramos y el boton para ver más detalles del producto.

Como solucionarian esto? Se agradece bastante!!

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código (en texto, no imagen) que has utilizado.

Comment: Mira te soy sincero, te respondí otra pregunta y no he recibido ningún feedback, en esa misma pregunta te dijeron que te leyeras las reglas y tu pasas de ello. Todo eso baja tus probabilidades de obtener respuestas. Si tú quieres resolver un problema debes ser el primer interesado. Debes leer el reglamento cuando participas en una comunidad, si te responden debes aceptar la respuesta o decir porque está mal y debes mostrar el código con un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible.

Comment: Hola OCHOA, Hola de nuevo Yussef, tienen toda la razón y les pido una disculpa, soy nuevo incursionando en este mundo y definitivamente tienen toda la razón, en el caso de la primera pregunta @Yussef disculpa, hice esta pregunta antes de ir a probar tu respuesta, hasta que probé tu codigo en mi proyecto vine y respondí, sino.. pues hubiera calificado / respondido sin evidencias, por eso el delay de marcar tu respuesta y/o escribirte feedback, sobre las reglas/requerimientos, en la otra pregunta me recomendaste poner código y ya hice lo que me recomendaste en mi nueva pregunta, de nuevo sorry

Comment: Estuve editando la pregunta, espero todo esto ayude, incluso puse el código que estoy utilizando actualmente y como se ve, alguna otra recomendación? Yussef o @OCHOA?

Comment: Sería bueno si adjuntaras el código completo para que tu código sea reproducible (incluyendo el css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr eso puedes usar css [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) y ocupando un `repeat` queda automáticamente responsivo.

Luego el truco para lograr exactamente lo que está en la foto que publicaste es colocar los bordes en los pesudos elementos `before` y `after` ambos con position:absolute. Luego toca jugar con los top,left, right y bottom para acomodar los bordes donde deseas. Con esto logramos 2 cosas:

1. El efecto de que los bordes superiores e inferiores son más angostos
2. De no hacerlo, los bordes quedarían uno al lado del otro, creando un efecto de un borde el doble de ancho de lo deseado.

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height:160px;
  background-color:blue;
  object-fit:cover;
}

.grilla{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,120px);
  justify-items:left;
}

.grilla > div {
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.grilla > div:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
      right: 8px;
    left: 8px;
  border-top: 2px dashed red;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed red;
}
.grilla > div:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    left: -1px;

  border-left: 2px dashed red;
  border-right: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grilla">
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>  
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>
  <div><img></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente! Gracias por ayudar!!